# How to import aws_lambda_permission in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

How can I use `terraform import` with resources of type `aws_lambda_permission` in terraform? What should the second argument be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time of writing Terraform does not have an importer for this resource, so it's not possible to import it automatically using the `terraform import` command.

Since a Lambda permission is a subordinate resource belonging to a Lambda function, once there *is* support for importing it the most likely way it would be handled is to import it as a side-effect of importing the function itself; the id of the permission alone is not enough information to retrieve it.

Answer (score 3):

For those landing on this it is now possible. 
`terraform import aws_lambda_permission.<your_resource_name> <lambda_function_name>/<permission_statement_id>`

The statement id (SID) can be found by under `permissions > Resource-based policy` for the lambda function on the AWS console.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the same permission with different `statement_id`, then remove the old lambda permission via aws cli:

`aws lambda remove-permission --function-name myfunction --statement-id myoldfunctionsid`