# How to construct import command for aws_lambda_permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Now that Terraform can [import lambda permissions](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_permission#import) (which was not possible when [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43771086/how-to-import-aws-lambda-permission-in-terraform) was made) how do I find the `function_name/statement_id` portion of the `import` arguments  for the `aws_lambda_permission` resource?

I guess this could be rephrased as: Where do I find the SID for the permission object when it has been created by, eg, the console?

In the `permissions` tab of the Lambda function I have this policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "11111111-1234-1234-1234-1234567891234",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:123456789012:function:MyLizardApp",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-2:123456789012:hfqy1l9g3m/*/*/*"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "22222222-1234-1234-1234-1234567891234",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:123456789012:function:MyLizardApp",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-2:123456789012:hfqy1l9g3m/*/*/"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The import command I'm attempting to use is this:

```
terraform import aws_lambda_permission.apigw_lambda_proxy MyLizardApp/InvokeFunction
```

I'm doing this to attempt to populate the terraform resource (this is described as one method of importing terraform in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64294627/71376)):

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigw_lambda_proxy" {
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigw_lambda_root" {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should just be in the Permissions tab in the Lambda function in the AWS console. The first section of that tab are the permissions that the Lambda function has, while the second part (titled `Resource-based policy`) has the permissions for invoking the Lambda function from other AWS services.

You should also be able to get it by using the AWS CLI's `aws lambda get-policy`. This will return the invocation policy as nested, escaped JSON which can be extracted with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```sh
aws lambda get-policy --function-name MY_EXAMPLE_FUNCTION | jq -r '.Policy | fromjson | .Statement[].Sid'
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of what the ID would look like please? I just can't identify where it is on the page and all the examples I've seen use unrealistic strings as placeholders.

Comment: I don't have any Lambda functions where I've created them via the AWS console but it should be in the section marked `Resource-based policy`. Have you tried running the AWS CLI command in the answer to retrieve it if you are unsure about where it is in the console?